# iCloud Key-Value never sync

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I have a huge problem for 3 days now.
I'm trying to use iCloud Key-Value storage on iOS but values never sync with iCloud without visible errors.
And when I say that it doesn't sync, it really never sync at all. I can let the app run for 15 minutes, close it and launch it again, values will still don't exist.

I have enabled iCloud on my App-ID on Apple Member Center.
I have enabled iCloud in xCode capabilities of my project.
Everything runs fine without error but when I'm trying to get my value, it doesn't exist at all.

Here is the code I use to communicate with iCloud(keep in mind that I need to use it with Unity3D):

```
extern "C" void UnitySendMessage(const char *, const char *, const char *);

@interface iCloudPlugin : NSObject
{
    NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *keyStore;
}
@end

@implementation iCloudPlugin

- (id) initClass
{

    if([NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] == nil){
        NSLog(@"iCloud not enabled");
    }else{
        keyStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyValueStoreDidChange:) name:NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification object:keyStore];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) synchronize
{
    NSLog(@"Syncing iCloud");
    if([keyStore synchronize])
    {
        NSLog(@"Successfully synced");
    }
}

- (void) addValue:(const char*)key value:(const char*)value
{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",key]);
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",value]);
    [keyStore setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",key] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",value ]];
    [self synchronize];
}

-(void) keyValueStoreDidChange: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Key/Value Changed"]);
}

- (const char*) getValue:(const char*)key
{
    NSString *storedString = [keyStore stringForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",key]];
    return [storedString UTF8String];
}

- (BOOL) hasKey:(const char*)key
{

    NSString *storedString = [keyStore stringForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",key]];
    if(storedString == nil){
        return NO;
    }else{
        return YES;
    }
}

- (void) removeKey:(const char*)key
{
    [keyStore removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",key]];
    [self synchronize];
}




@end

extern "C" {
    void *_InitICloud();
    void _Synchronize(void *instance);
    void _AddValue(void *instance, const char *key, const char *value);
    const char *_GetValue(void *instance, const char *key);
    BOOL _HasKey(void *instance, const char *key);
    void _RemoveKey(void *instance, const char *key);
}

void *_InitICloud()
{
    id instance = [[iCloudPlugin alloc] initClass];
    return (void *)instance;
}

void _Synchronize(void *instance)
{
    iCloudPlugin *iCloudInstance = (iCloudPlugin *) instance;
    [iCloudInstance synchronize];
}

void _AddValue(void *instance, const char *key, const char *value){
    iCloudPlugin *iCloudInstance = (iCloudPlugin *) instance;
    [iCloudInstance addValue:key value:value];
}

const char *_GetValue(void *instance, const char *key)
{
    iCloudPlugin *iCloudInstance = (iCloudPlugin *) instance;
    return [iCloudInstance getValue:key];
}

BOOL _HasKey(void *instance, const char *key)
{
    iCloudPlugin *iCloudInstance = (iCloudPlugin *) instance;
    return [iCloudInstance hasKey:key];
}

void _RemoveKey(void *instance, const char *key)
{
    iCloudPlugin *iCloudInstance = (iCloudPlugin *) instance;
    [iCloudInstance removeKey:key];
}
```

So every time I launch my App, I check for a key named "myKey" that has "test" value.

If it doesn't exist I create it and if it exist I display it.

Without suspens, the hasKey function always return NO.

I tried to call it at different place of my app or by syncing it many times but I never have my value when I relaunch the app.

I looked at the iPhone 5 (running iOS 8.1) logs and there is no log about iCloud.
I have read on another topic that there are hidden iCloud log that you can access by syncing with iCloud, then navigate to ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/iPhone de *******/DiagnosticLogs.

In these logs I can find sometimes this:

```
Nov  4 16:57:29 iPhone-de-******* librariand[139] <Debug>: cancelled, closing fd 4
Nov  4 16:57:29 iPhone-de-******* librariand[139] <Debug>: client process 140 does not have a valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement
Nov  4 16:57:29 iPhone-de-******* librariand[139] <Debug>: not tracking pid 140 since it does not require us to enable push
Nov  4 16:57:29 iPhone-de-******* librariand[139] <Debug>: application identifier for process 140 = bird
Nov  4 16:57:29 iPhone-de-******* librariand[139] <Debug>: received request 12 from client 140 (bird): <dictionary: 0x175749a0> { count = 1, contents =
                "Request Type" => <uint64: 0x17683ed0>: 12
        }
Nov  4 16:57:29 iPhone-de-******* librariand[139] <Debug>: container com.apple.shoebox has 0 bytes evictable
Nov  4 16:57:29 iPhone-de-******* librariand[139] <Debug>: client connection error: Connection invalid
```

The problem is I couldn't find any com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers in the iCloud entitlements. 
So I created it and gives it our AppID value but it doesn't work either (+ it displays an error in xCode because it doesn't recognize it).

I tried to remove all Provisioning Profiles from the phone, it doesn't change anything.
I tried to disable Cellular Data in iCloud, it doesn't change anything(I also tried to enable it again, guess what, doesn't change anything).

I'm really stuck right now and Googled pretty much everything I can find related to this error.

Thank you for your help.